# How to do aggregate sum by time range in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, time, dataset, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe as below:

```
**df**
Cust_name   time    freq
Andrew       0       4
Dillain      1       2
Alma         2       3
Andrew       1       4
Kiko         2       1
Sarah        2       8
Sarah        0       3
```

I want to calculate the sum of frequency by the time range provided for each cust_name. Example: If I select time range 0 to 2 for Andrew, it will give me sum of freq: 4+4= 8. And for Sarah, it will give me 8+3=11. I have tried it in the following ways just to get the time range, but do not know how to do the rest, as I am very new to R:

```
df[(df$time>=0 & df$time<=2),]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr`.
To make your code reproducible, you should add the creation of your dataframe in your post. Copy and pasting everything is time consuming.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  cust_name = c('Andrew', 'Dillain', 'Alma', 'Andrew', 'Kiko', 'Sarah', 'Sarah'),
  time = c(0,1,2,1,2,2,0),
  freq = c(4,2,3,4,1,8,3)
)

df %>%
  filter(time >=0, time <=2) %>%
  group_by(cust_name) %>%
  summarise(sum_freq = sum(freq))
```